# Verb form of "spontaneous human combustion"

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs

In English there are plenty of examples of noun-verbs. What are the rules for making more complex compound noun structures into transitive verbs? In particular I would like explanations involving the phrase *spontaneous human combustion*.

Would the following work?

> He **spontaneously human-combusted**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Human* is not necessary here as you've already established it with *he*. So, you could say "he combusted spontaneously," or "he spontaneously combusted."

Comment: I am trying to understand the rules of how nouns are made into verbs and chose this as an example of a phenomena with a particular name phrase.  I appreciate the reconstruction ; any chance you could add in how to make the phrase a verb and the rules governing the transition? If not an explanation of why it can't work the way I'm asking is great too.

Comment: @mfg: Do you have any other examples? I'm having trouble coming up with other phrases like _spontaneous human combustion_ that might be verbed. Otherwise, I think the rule would usually be to turn the noun of the phrase into a verb and the modifying adjective into an adverb as in my answer. If there were more than one adjective I can see where it might get confusing. Is this your question? Again, more examples might help.

Comment: I am surprised but i couldn't come up with any others either; so your answer works for me

Answer (score 1):

I would use *autoimmolation*.

Comment: That's a noun. The verb would be to autoimmolate.

Comment: Hmm, I like that word.